# Show and Hide using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

There are number of examples for add and remove in jquery. 
But my code is bit different to examples. when i click add it show second and if i click again on add i want show third as well as when i click remove hide the third also  until five. Here is my code

CSS

```
#second {
    display: none;
}
#third {
    display: none;
}
#forth {
    display: none;
}
#fifth {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="header">
     <a href="#" id="add1">add</a> - <a href="#" id="remove">remove</a>
    <div id="first"><a href="#">first</a></div>            
    <div id="second"><a href="#">second</a></div>
    <div id="third"><a href="#">third</a></div>
    <div id="forth"><a href="#">forth</a></div>
    <div id="fifth"><a href="#">fifth</a></div>
</div>`
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#add1").click(function() {
            $("#second").show();
        });
        $("#remove").click(function() {
            $("#second").hide();
        });
    });
```

**HERE IS CODE**
 [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siddhuphp/UpX3L/1865/)

Comment: Make an _Array_ of the _id_ values in order, i.e. `var id_arr = ['first', 'second', ..., 'fifth'];` now you just need to keep an integer variable `var i = 0;` which lets you know the index to show. Now, every click show elem with id `id_arr[i % id_arr.length]`, increment `i`

Comment: DEAR @PaulS. CAN SHOW IT IN JSFIDDLE. I TRIED BUT DIDN'T WORK. BUT I UNDERSTAND YOUR CONCEPT.  CAN YOU PLEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach you can use. First, add a class to all elements that you want to show / hide. In this case I used class `toggle`:

```
<div id="header">
    <a href="#" id="add1">add</a> - <a href="#" id="remove">remove</a>
    <div id="first" class="toggle"><a href="#">first</a></div>            
    <div id="second" class="toggle"><a href="#">second</a></div>
    <div id="third" class="toggle"><a href="#">third</a></div>
    <div id="forth" class="toggle"><a href="#">forth</a></div>
    <div id="fifth" class="toggle"><a href="#">fifth</a></div>
</div>
```

Then when you are adding an element, use function `first` to find first not visible element with class `toggle` and show it. When you want to remove element, use function `last` to find last not visible element and hide it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // when add is clicked, show first not visible element with class 'toggle'
    $("#add1").click(function() {
        $('.toggle:not(:visible)').first().show();
    });
    // when remove is clicked, hide last visible element with class 'toggle'
    $("#remove").click(function() {
        $('.toggle:visible').last().hide();
    });
});
```

Here is [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UpX3L/1868/)

Comment: NOT WORKING @dotnetom. CAN YOU SHOW ME IN JSFIDDLE ?

Comment: @SiddhuSiddharthaRoy I added the link

Comment: Thanks :-)  you saved my time.